# What tweaks can be used to make Ubuntu run faster on a weak CPU?

Tags: performance, cpu, cpu-load, tweak, intel-cpu

Most tweaks pertain to low RAM systems or to making the system use the HDD less. In my system with a SSD and 8GB of RAM, the CPU (or SoC in the case of my Intel Celeron N3150) is the bottleneck. I would like to stick to vanilla Ubuntu instead of going with a lighter alternative as I'm used to the workflow. I'm primarily using the PC for office work and browsing the web (Firefox, Thunderbird and LibreOffice). Are there any tweaks that will help with low processing power?

Comment: Switching to a 2D desktop environment should a help quite a bit. Give XFCE and/or LXDE a try

Comment: What about installing a lightweight window manager such as i3 and using it instead of unity? Will it be as fast or faster than Lubuntu?